# how to set IBM MQ topic to share message only within same applications

Tags: ibm-mq, jms-topic

this is what I want to achieve with IBM MQ:

I have a topic in place, and 2 different applications (A1,A2) subscribing the topic. each application has 2 instances, i.e. (A1-I1,A1-I2,A2-I1,A2-I2).
when a message (M1) is published to the topic, the message will be received by both applications A1 & A2. but within A1, only one instance (A1-I1 or A1-I2) can receive this message M1, the same goes to instances of A2.

is it possible with IBM MQ topics and JMS?

Comment: Look up shared subscriptions.  As long as each pair has a matching client id and sub name they can share the subscriptions.   Each pair needs a unique client id from the other pairs.

Comment: Just thinking about the use case where the same message is to be processed by two applications? Shared subscription can be used for load sharing among multiple instances of an application. One of the instance will process a message.

Comment: @Shashi it seems that is what he is describing. Two different shared subscriptions each with two consumers subscribing to them.   Only one subscriber to each shared subscription will get any published message.

Comment: @JoshMc it says "I have a topic in place, and 2 different applications (A1,A2) subscribing the topic". Orignator can possibly clarify.

Comment: @Shashi it also says "but within A1, only one instance (A1-I1 or A1-I2) can receive this message M1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked up shared subscription mentioned in the comment, but I find it (IBM MQ) has a limitation that the shared subscription can only be accessed by one JVM, i.e. two application instances can't access the the shared subscription at the same time, so I give up this purely pub/sub direction.

I managed to make it work by making the applications listen to the destination queue of subscription instead of directly subscription. I defined in the queue manager subscription SUB.A1 with destination queue of SUB.A1.QUEUE and subscription SUB.A2 with destination queue of SUB.A2.QUEUE. all instances of application A1 will listen to SUB.A1.QUEUE and A2 to SUB.A2.QUEUE. and everything works as expected.

The above setup is all applications connecting to the same queue manager. if there is a queue manager cluster of multiple QMs, just define the subscription destination queues as cluster queues and it will work as well

Comment: Have you tried shared subscriptions, I am certain there is not a "one JVM" requirement.   Just the sub name and client ID must match.

Comment: I setup a application with mq-jms-spring-boot-starter, defined a  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory with subscriptionShared & pubSubDomain set to true, and @JmsListener specifying destination and subscription. I started two instances of this applications and then sent messages to the topic. One instance was getting all the messages and the other got nothing. Then I came across this document from IBM [Cloned and shared subscriptions] suggesting cloned subscriptions can enable consumers from multi JVMs but not mentioned what is the case in shared subscriptions, so I just assumed it cant

Comment: If you didn't get an error when starting the subscriber and both did not get messages, then it is working as designed.  MQ does not guarantee that messages with be load balancered across 2 consumers.   In fact MQ by default delivers to the most recent getter.  If you send sufficient volume you should see both subscribers receiving messages

Comment: I see, I just tried some dozens of messages, maybe the volume was not enough.. but if I want to load balance same subscription across QMs (i.e. A1-I1, A1-I2 listen to different QM), neither cloned nor shared subscriptions can do that, right?

Comment: That is correct,  shared subscribers need to be against the same queue manager.